# Redux: Action is being called properly but reducer is not updating the state, just keeping the initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been building an application using React, Redux, Redux-thunk.
While calling action, the payload and type are properly received by the reducer but it is not modifying them.

- My Reducer:

```js
import EditorActionTypes from './editor.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    editorModified: false,
    tabs: [
        {
            name: 'main.js',
            active: true
        },
        {
            name: 'setup.js',
            active: false
        }
    ]
};

const editorReducer = ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) => {
    switch (action.payload) {
        case EditorActionTypes.SELECT_TAB:
            return {
                ...state,
                tabs: [
                    ...state.tabs.map( 
                        (tab, index) => index === action.payload
                            ? tab.active = true
                            : tab.active = false
                        )
                ]
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default editorReducer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch condition is wrong,
Reducer function should check for action.type

```
switch (action.type) {
        case EditorActionTypes.SELECT_TAB:
            return {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problematic part, I think, is this:

```
                 ...state.tabs.map( 
                        (tab, index) => index === action.payload
                            ? tab.active = true
                            : tab.active = false
                        )
```

You are not returning anything from the function inside map. You should return tab objects, instead.

```
                 ...state.tabs.map( 
                        (tab, index) => ({ 
                           ...tab,
                           isActive: index === action.payload
                        }))
```

And as @Gangadhar Gandi pointed out, you should switch on the action.type, not the action.payload

Comment: Thank you too as well. This was next in line I noticed after resolving my question thought GangadharGandi answer. Long-night typos! Totally my bad. :D